# Get executable name in syscall?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

So I am writing a system call in Linux. I want to print a message that looks like

```
printk(KERN_DEBUG "PROC_DEBUG [%s, %s]: %s", executable, current->pid, message);
```

Where executable is the name of the executable that is created when I link a source file against the library used to call the syscall. So if I run the command "cc -o <program_name> sourcefile.c -L ./a -lfilename", <program_name> is what I want to print for the executable. (The pid is the process ID of the process that is running the executable, and message is a parameter I pass to the system call.)

I was trying to use this code to get the executable name

```
struct task_struct *task = get_current();
char task_com[TASK_COM_LEN];
get_task_com(task_com, task);
```

But I am getting an error that 'TASK_COM_LEN' is undeclared, so what am I missing?

Is there an easier way to get the executable name? Something like "current->executable"? I'm not finding any great matches on the web.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out; `current->com` is what I was looking for.

Comment: It should be `current->comm` with 2 `m`'s, not `current->com`